# How to Pause and start the timer for loading views at different time intervals

Tags: iphone

I Paused the timer by using `invalidate` but not getting it how to start timer again to load multiple views where `NSTimer` is not constant, it varies for all views and specially when user can hit pause on any view and once user hit pause again to resume audio file, program should start loading views from that point.

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender 
{

if  

  ([audioPlayer isPlaying]){

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"play.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

  [audioPlayer pause];

 [timer invalidate];

  } else {

 [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pause.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  [audioPlayer play];

  self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11 target:self selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

  }  

}

- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{
FirstViewController *viewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:23 target:self selector:@selector(secondViewController) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[viewController release];

}

-(void)secondViewController {
SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];

secondController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:secondController.view]; 

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:27 target:self selector:@selector(ThirdviewController) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[secondController release];
}
```

Anyone please help to sort this out.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do here. Your timer only runs once in each case. I don't understand "pausing" the timer.